# puzzling javascript array syntax

Tags: javascript

I'm puzzled by this construction. It's from a published npm module.  It seems the author knows his javascript.  Versions of it appear several times in the module.

```
[].concat( opts['boolean'] ).filter( Boolean ).forEach( function( key ){
  flags.bools[key] = true;
});
```

Since it doesn't modify the original array and also the member 'boolean' is known from the outset, why not just:

```
opts.boolean.filter(Boolean).forEach(....
```

Comment: `opts['boolean']` *probably* isn't an Array, so you can't filter or map over it.

Comment: While the author probably wants a shorthand to avoid calling `.concat` on non-genuine Array objects, the `.filter()` will keep any truthy values, so if `opts.boolean` is a plain object, it will be doing `flags.bools["[object Object]"] = true;`. Maybe the author is OK with that, but it doesn't seem like the best approach.

Comment: IMO, a better way would be `if (Array.isArray(opts.boolean)) { opts.boolean.filter(Boolean).forEach(...) }`

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that opts.boolean is an optional user supplied value.  When present it must be an Array but it may be undefined.

Comment: I had to look this one up.  Boolean called w/o new  returns a *primitive* true/false value depending on the truthiness of the argument.

so the .filter returns all truthy entries in opts.boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because of this:

`[].concat(undefined)  // => [undefined]`

`undefined.filter(...)  // => ERROR`